# How to infinite click on show more button to generate a full page and then collect data links?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to collect a maximum of profile links on Khan Academy and then select some specific data on each of these profiles to store them into a CSV file.

Here is my script to get profile links. Then scrape specific data on each of these profiles. And then store them in a csv file.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/v/what-are-algorithms')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find the profile links
profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
profile_list=[]
for links in profiles:
    links_no_list = links.extract()
    text_link = links_no_list['href']
    text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
    final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
    profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

#create the csv file
filename = "khanscraptry1.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date\n"
f.write(headers)

#for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
for link in profile_list: 
    print("Scrapping ",link)
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(link)
    r.html.render(sleep=5)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
    user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
    if user_info_table is not None:
        dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
    else:
        dates=points=videos='NA'

    user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
    data = {}
    for gettext in user_socio_table:
        category = gettext.find('span')
        category_text = category.text.strip()
        number = category.previousSibling.strip()
        data[category_text] = number

    full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
    for header_value in full_data_keys:
        if header_value not in data.keys():
            data[header_value]='NA'

    user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
    if user_calendar is not None:
        last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
        try:
            last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
        except TypeError:
            last_activity_date='NA'
    else:
        last_activity_date='NA'
    f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "\n") #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead

f.close()
```

This first script should work fine. Now, my problem is that this script found about 40 profile links: `print(len(profile_list))` return `40`.

If I could click on show more button (on : `https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/v/what-are-algorithms`), then I will get more profile links (and thus more profiles to scrape).

That script is infinitely clicking on show more button, until there is no show more button:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome() #watch out, change if you are not using Chrome
driver.get("https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/v/what-are-algorithms")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

def showmore(self):
       while True:
             try:
               driver.implicitly_wait(5)
               showmore = self.find_element_by_class_name("button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203")
               showmore.click()
             except NoSuchElementException:
               break

showmore(driver)
```

This second script should also work fine.

My question is: how can I merge these two scripts? How to make BeautifulSoup, Selenium and Requests work together?

In other words: How can I apply the second script to get a full page and then treat it into the first script?

Comment: It seems that the same profile is being scrapped two times, is this required?

Comment: No it is not required (actually I would like to have unique links), I can do `link in profile_list[::2]:` instead of `link in profile_list:` like you said here in your comment `https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892333/10972294`. But your proposition down below is way more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: how can I merge these two scripts? How to make
>   BeautifulSoup, Selenium and Requests work together?

*You don't need to.* Selenium alone can do all of the actions required as well as get the data required. Another alternative is to use selenium  do actions (such as click), get the page_source and let BeautifulSoup do the parsing. I have used the second option. Please note that this is b'coz I am more comfortable with BeautifulSoup and not b'coz selenium can't get the data required.

*Merged Script*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
driver = webdriver.Chrome() #watch out, change if you are not using Chrome
driver.get("https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/v/what-are-algorithms")
while True:
    try:
        showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="v/what-are-algorithms-panel"]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div[4]/button')))
        showmore.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        break

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
#find the profile links
profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
profile_list=[]
for links in profiles:
    links_no_list = links.extract()
    text_link = links_no_list['href']
    text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
    final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
    profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

#remove duplicates
#remove the below line if you want the dupliactes
profile_list=list(set(profile_list))

#print number of profiles we got
print(len(profile_list))
#create the csv file
filename = "khanscraptry1.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date\n"
f.write(headers)


#for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
for link in profile_list:
    #to avoid Scrapping same profile multiple times
    #print each profile link we are about to scrap
    print("Scrapping ",link)
    driver.get(link)
    #wait for content to load
    #if profile does not exist skip
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="widget-list"]/div[1]/div[1]')))
    except TimeoutException:
        continue
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
    if user_info_table is not None:
        dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
    else:
        dates=points=videos='NA'

    user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
    data = {}
    for gettext in user_socio_table:
        category = gettext.find('span')
        category_text = category.text.strip()
        number = category.previousSibling.strip()
        data[category_text] = number

    full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
    for header_value in full_data_keys:
        if header_value not in data.keys():
            data[header_value]='NA'

    user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
    if user_calendar is not None:
        last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
        try:
            last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
        except TypeError:
            last_activity_date='NA'
    else:
        last_activity_date='NA'
    f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "\n")
```

*Sample console Output*

```
551
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_888977072825430260337359/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_883316191998827325047066/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_1174374133389372329315932/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_175131632601098270919916/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_120532771190025953629523/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_443636490088836886070300/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_1202505937095267213741452/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_464949975690601300556189/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_727801603402106934190616/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_808370995413780397188230/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_427134832219441477944618/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_232193725763932936324703/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_167043118118112381390423/
Scrapping  https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_17327330351684516133566/
...
```

*Sample File Output (khanscraptry1.csv)*

```
link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_888977072825430260337359/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Tuesday Dec 8 2015
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_883316191998827325047066/,5 years ago,2152299,513,10,884,34,16,82,108,1290,360,Monday Aug 27 2018
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_1174374133389372329315932/,NA,NA,NA,2,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,NA
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_175131632601098270919916/,NA,NA,NA,173,19,2,0,NA,NA,128,3,Thursday Feb 7 2019
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_120532771190025953629523/,NA,NA,NA,9,0,3,18,NA,NA,4,4,Tuesday Oct 11 2016
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_443636490088836886070300/,7 years ago,3306784,987,10,231,49,11,8,156,10,NA,Sunday Jul 22 2018
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_1202505937095267213741452/,NA,NA,NA,2,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Thursday Apr 28 2016
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_464949975690601300556189/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Friday Mar 16 2018
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_727801603402106934190616/,5 years ago,2927634,1049,6,562,332,9,NA,NA,20,NA,NA
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_808370995413780397188230/,NA,NA,NA,NA,19,192,0,NA,NA,52,NA,Saturday Jan 19 2019
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_427134832219441477944618/,NA,NA,NA,2,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Tuesday Sep 18 2018
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_232193725763932936324703/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Monday May 15 2017
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_167043118118112381390423/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Friday Mar 1 2019
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_17327330351684516133566/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,NA
https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_146705727466233630898864/,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,Thursday Apr 5 2018
```

Comment: script is working fine thanks!
Now tough we are working on this link `https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/intro-to-algorithms/v/what-are-algorithms`
Can we apply the merged script but on multiple `driver.get()` links?
For example : I take this link `https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming`
Then create a list of every content course links with `class='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki'`
Can driver.get() take the output of this list (and then execute the merged script above)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear enough with my previous comment. Let me know if I should create a post for it. (I do have some code, but not really working).

Comment: @RobZ You could store each link and the class to a dictionary and the loop through   it. It is always better to ask a new question. Other users may be able to find out better solutions to the problem which you or me may not find.

Comment: I think I've coded the dictionary and the loop right : `https://stackoverflow.com/q/54975740/10972294` ? But I can't be for sure the script is taking way too much time.