# How to make Selenium and beautifulsoup work faster?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to scrape as many profile links as possible on Khan Academy. And then scrape some specific data on each of these profiles.

My problem here is simple: this script is taking way to much time and I can't be for sure that it is working the right way.

Here is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find course steps links
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')
list_courses={}

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course
#print(list_courses)

# my goal is to loop the below script with each "course link" that I got above with list_courses
for courses_step in list_courses.values():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(courses_step)
    # to click show more button to scrape more profile links, that take lot of time
    while True:
        try:
            showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203')))
            showmore.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            break

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    #find the profile links
    profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
    profile_list=[]
    for links in profiles:
        links_no_list = links.extract()
        text_link = links_no_list['href']
        text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
        final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
        profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

    #remove duplicates
    profile_list=list(set(profile_list))

    #print number of profiles per course link we got
    print('in this link:')
    print(courses_step)
    print('we have this number of profiles:')
    print(len(profile_list))
    #create the csv file
    filename = "khanscrapetry1.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date\n"
    f.write(headers)

    #for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
    for link in profile_list:
        #to avoid Scraping same profile multiple times
        #print each profile link we are about to scrape
        print("Scraping ",link)
        driver.get(link)
        #wait for content to load
        #if profile does not exist skip
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="widget-list"]/div[1]/div[1]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            continue
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
        if user_info_table is not None:
            dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
        else:
            dates=points=videos='NA'

        user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
        data = {}
        for gettext in user_socio_table:
            category = gettext.find('span')
            category_text = category.text.strip()
            number = category.previousSibling.strip()
            data[category_text] = number

        full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
        for header_value in full_data_keys:
            if header_value not in data.keys():
                data[header_value]='NA'

        user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
        if user_calendar is not None:
            last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
            try:
                last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
            except TypeError:
                last_activity_date='NA'
        else:
            last_activity_date='NA'
        f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "\n")
```

This script is supposed to work, but I'm not sure because It's way too long/slow to verify.

How can I make it work faster? Is it possible to save a progress and re-run it later? Or maybe run simultaneously different scripts for each course link?

For example the first link in `list_courses` took 1 hour and 30 minutes just to finish the while loop (to get 3187 profiles links).

Comment: One thing that would make it a lot faster is to run the fetches in parallel by creating multiple instances of chrome driver each running in own thread, and giving each a part of the list to fetch. You'll need to set up some sort of locking mechanism if you want them all writing to same file though. Also, if you create a bunch of instances like this, you'll want to run them in headless mode.

Comment: @J.Taylor Interesting, how do you do that?

Comment: Look into [concurrent.Futures.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) for how to use threads in general. If you have specific questions about multithreading, create a new post here asking about them. But in general, you want to (1) create several instances of selenium driver (2) create a list of all URLs that need to be processed. (3) for each URL in list, submit it to the pool with one of the drivers that isn't being used. (4)  When an individual driver is done processing the page, reuse it to process a new page by submitting to pool with new URL.

Comment: @J.Taylor I've just created a question here `https://stackoverflow.com/q/55033633/10972294` Let me know if I should be more precise or add more information in my question.