# How to use threading with selenium for web scraping?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My main objective is to scrape as many profile links as possible on Khan Academy. And then scrape some specific data on each of these profiles.

My goal with this question is to use threading to make my script work much faster.

So I will present my code in two part: first part without threading an second part with threading.

This the original code without threading:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find course steps links
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')
list_courses={}

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course
#print(list_courses)

# my goal is to loop the below script with each "course link" that I got above with list_courses
for courses_step in list_courses.values():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(courses_step)
    while True:
        try:
            showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203')))
            showmore.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            break

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    #find the profile links
    profiles = soup.find_all(href=re.compile("/profile/kaid"))
    profile_list=[]
    for links in profiles:
        links_no_list = links.extract()
        text_link = links_no_list['href']
        text_link_nodiscussion = text_link[:-10]
        final_profile_link ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+text_link_nodiscussion
        profile_list.append(final_profile_link)

    #remove duplicates
    profile_list=list(set(profile_list))

    #print number of profiles we got
    print('in this link:')
    print(courses_step)
    print('we have this number of profiles:')
    print(len(profile_list))
    #create the csv file
    filename = "khanscrapetry1.csv"
    f = open(filename, "w")
    headers = "link, date_joined, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx, last_date\n"
    f.write(headers)

    #for each profile link, scrape the specific data and store them into the csv
    for link in profile_list:
        #to avoid Scraping same profile multiple times
        #print each profile link we are about to scrape
        print("Scraping ",link)
        driver.get(link)
        #wait for content to load
        #if profile does not exist skip
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="widget-list"]/div[1]/div[1]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            continue
        soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
        user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
        if user_info_table is not None:
            dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
        else:
            dates=points=videos='NA'

        user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
        data = {}
        for gettext in user_socio_table:
            category = gettext.find('span')
            category_text = category.text.strip()
            number = category.previousSibling.strip()
            data[category_text] = number

        full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks'] #might change answers to answer because when it's 1 it's putting NA instead
        for header_value in full_data_keys:
            if header_value not in data.keys():
                data[header_value]='NA'

        user_calendar = soup.find('div',class_='streak-calendar-scroll-container')
        if user_calendar is not None:
            last_activity = user_calendar.find('span',class_='streak-cell filled')
            try:
                last_activity_date = last_activity['title']
            except TypeError:
                last_activity_date='NA'
        else:
            last_activity_date='NA'
        f.write(link + "," + dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "," + last_activity_date + "\n")
```

This code should work fine. But the problem is: it's taking way too much time.

And here is the script that include threading:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import concurrent.futures

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming#intro-to-programming')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

#find course steps links
courses_links = soup.find_all(class_='link_1uvuyao-o_O-nodeStyle_cu2reh-o_O-nodeStyleIcon_4udnki')
list_courses={}

for links in courses_links:
    courses = links.extract()
    link_course = courses['href']
    title_course= links.find(class_='nodeTitle_145jbuf')
    span_title_course=title_course.span
    text_span=span_title_course.text.strip()
    final_link_course ='https://www.khanacademy.org'+link_course
    list_courses[text_span]=final_link_course

#that's my driver function
def showmore(url, timeout):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    while True:
        try:
            showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'button_1eqj1ga-o_O-shared_1t8r4tr-o_O-default_9fm203')))
            showmore.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            break

#that's my pool
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    #do this in my pool
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(showmore, url, 20): url for url in list_courses.values()}
```

As you can see the second script is not doing everything yet. I still have to add the whole data scraping / writing process.

My question is: How to create threadings for the scrape and write parts? How should I order these threadings?

More broadly: How to make my script run as fast as possible?

Comment: The easy version is have each thread write their own file and then after the run is complete, stitch the files together.

Comment: threading on webdriver may not be the right way https://stackoverflow.com/a/30829406/6770946. yoo may want to consider using grequests which allow threading of requests instead of tabs in browser.

Comment: @JeffC What do you mean? How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "more broadly" question, you ought to use `asyncio` in conjuction with `requests` or similar packages.  A decent guide for doing so can be found [here](https://medium.com/@santhoshhari/efficient-web-scraping-with-pythons-asynchronous-programming-6b9e730f1ff7). Threading is not built for running asynchronous http requests.

I can't show you how to do write your code with asyncio because I hardly know how to use it myself, and it would likely take hundreds of lines of code to finish.

If you want a *quick* solution to increase performance using the code you already have, you should set your selenium browser to *headless* mode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH_HERE', chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: switching to headless won't make a large difference in performance

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Yes unfortunately headless mode is not going to change much, do you have suggestions?

Comment: yes many, but new questions shouldn't be raised in answer comments.